# Vectors and indices

Tags: spacing, superscripts, vector

I'm trying to write a vector, **r**, which is raised to the power two.
Currently this is what I'm using

```
$\vec{r}_{i}^{2}$
```

but the vector arrow and power of two are overlapping. Is there anyway I could change the spacing in the power, or should I do it another way?

Comment: this adds just a little space before the `2`: $\vec{r}_{i}^{\,2}$

Comment: You could also consider `r_i^2`, since the square of a vector is the square of its magnitude (assuming you define magnitude using the L2 norm, as is typical). This is the most common way to write squared vectors in many fields of physics. If you want to preserve the vector notation, consider setting vectors in bold instead of using arrows.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses. Since this is for my personal notes I'll go for the more aesthetically pleasing option of $\vec{r}_{i}^{\,2}$.

Answer (score 8):

i nearly always agree with david, but i think a little less space is called for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\vec{r}_{i}^{2}
\quad
{\vec{r}_{i}}^{\,2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Do you feel that aligning the power outside the vertical boundary of i is more reflective of the fact that the power applies to the vector--including the index? Playing devil's advocate here, I agree your solution is cosmetically more pleasing then David's but wonder if it should not intersect with i's bubble space.

Comment: logically, i guess that placing the superscript outside the "bubble" would be semantically more correct.  however, if i were to try to make this expression both maximally "pleasing" and maximally "correct", i would also shift the subscript in a bit more with `\!` -- the shape of the *r* is "difficult" in this case; if the italic correction were decreased, then a non-embellished *r* followed by most other lowercase italic letters would be too close.  taking considerations like that into account, tex's adjustments for shape are too simplistic -- but still better than other systems'.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\[
\vec{r}_{i}^{2}
\quad
{\vec{r}_{i}{}}^{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What could go wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\newif\ifvec
\def\advancedsp#1{\sp{\ifvec\,\global\vecfalse\fi#1}}%
\let\normalvec\vec
\def\vec{\vectrue\normalvec}%
\catcode`\^=\active
\let^\advancedsp

\[ \vec{r}_{i}^{2} \]
\end{document}
```